# How can I redefine variables in C?

Tags: c, variables, redefinition, redefine

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 365, j = 100, result = i + j;

    printf("i + j is %i\n", result);

    int i = 100, j = 1;
    printf("i + j is %i\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

9.c:10:10: error: declaration shadows a local variable [-Werror,-Wshadow]
9.c:8:9: error: redefinition of 'i'

Comment: I've reformatted and tagged as C since you're using `<stdio.h>`. Do retag if it's C++.

Comment: " redefinition of 'i'"  Well... look at the code. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `int i = 100` with `i = 100`.

You are not allowed to redeclare a variable in the same scope in C and C++. But you can set `i` to a different value, which is what my change does.

Finally, if you want the final output of `result` to be the sum of the *new* values of `i` and `j`, then you have to recompute. Put `result = i + j;` just before the `printf` call.

Comment: Output is i + j is 465
i + j is 465

Comment: That's because you don't re-evalute `result` after changing `i` and `j`. I've amended the answer.